# Binding from Firebasedatabase to Image in CollectionView depending on Dark or Light theme

Tags: maui

I am Binding a Image in a CollectionView from a `FirebaseDatabase` with some Labels.

In the FirebaseDatabase i change the Image in `Pic` or when i use Binding to `Picdark` in the Picdark.
The images are in the folder Images , that works fine. Change the name in the Database and an other image is showing in the CollectionView.

[image]

This one i want to use for the Light Theme.

```
 <Image
                                BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                                Grid.Column="1"
                                Aspect="AspectFill"
                                HeightRequest="60"
                                       Source="{Binding Pic}"
                                WidthRequest="60" />
```

And this for the Dark Theme.

```
 <Image
                                BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                                Grid.Column="1"
                                Aspect="AspectFill"
                                HeightRequest="60"
                                       Source="{Binding Picdark}"
                                WidthRequest="60" />
                            </Border>
```

Now the question , what do i change to make the Binding `Pic` for Light and `Picdark` for Dark Theme.
This is what i tryed but nothing is showing.

```
 <Image
                                    Grid.Column="1"
                                    Aspect="AspectFill"
                                    BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                                    HeightRequest="60"
                                    Source="{AppThemeBinding Light={Binding Pic},
                                                             Dark={Binding Picdark}}"
                                    WidthRequest="60" />
```

Answer (score 0):

`AppThemeBinding` isn't a `BindableObject`, `AppThemeBinding.Light` isn't a `BindableProperty`, so you cannot use `DynamicResource` or `Binding` with it.

But you can change different images with special images in folder `Resources/Images` depending on the app theme.

Please refer to the following code:

```
                               <Image 
                                
                                Aspect="AspectFill"
                                BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                                HeightRequest="80"
                                WidthRequest="80"
                                Source="{AppThemeBinding Light= test1.png,
                                                         Dark= test2.png}"
                                />
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Jessie , i used that for Light and Dark.  I tryed to change the image to a Bindable source from FireBasedatabase . Have to try something else. Thanks

Comment: Hi @Bas H, if my reply is useful for this problem, could you please mark it as answered so that it will help others who have similar problems? Thanks in advance. :)